# Run two commands, one after the other, on digitalocean app platform

Tags: django, digital-ocean, python-huey

I want to automatically start huey (a background task manager) going when I deploy a Django site on Digital Ocean's "App" platform. It provides a "run command" box where one can input commands when deploying (after the server is built).

I cannot work out why this isn't working:

```
gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm core.wsgi; python manage.py run_huey
```

I've tried the "&&" separator but that doesn't work either. The "python manage.py run_huey" command just doesn't get run.

Answer (score 0):

Very minor mistake. It's a single "&" in between the two commands.